# Video Quality with Lync 2013 custom client using UI Suppression

Tags: lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I've built a WPF application using the Lync SDK with UISuppression. One of the screens in the app features a full screen video call via Lync. I used this open source library to do the Lync video calling. https://github.com/tomorgan/Lync-UISuppression-VideoAutoAnswer

Unfortunately the quality of the fullscreen video is not great, it's as if it's a low resolution video that has been scaled up. When I do a fullscreen video call from the actual Lync client the video is crisp and sharp.

My test case is using my custom developed application to call another user using the standard Lync 2013 client. It's the video rendered within the custom application that is of poor quality.

Using the Lync SDK with UI Suppression is there any control that I have over the quality of the video?

Comment: Sorry for ignoring you on Twitter, been slammed and didn't have a good answer either! We're talking about this in the office now. Some ideas: maybe the SDK just doesn't do HD video..though this seems unlikely. Something to try: what happens if you resize the window to full screen before you attach the video: i.e. wondering if the video stream gets "fixed" to a size when it first starts. Unfortunately don't have the time to test this out myself right now, but hoping someone else knows more!

Comment: Cheers Tom - my app is actually a kiosk app so it defaults to be fullscreen the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

The [latest Lync client updates are out](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2881013), and whilst looking through them, I saw something which made me think of your problem.

2968248 Lync 2013 video quality is low when you scale up the size of the video window in UI suppression mode.

I wonder if, once applying that patch, the problem is resolved? That would be good!

-tom

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that setting the render window in full screen is not enough and you will get bad quality. You must first set the window size to HD and only afterwards enable full screen. This way it will work.

Here is my code (I have tested this is working):

```
    private void showMaximized( VideoWindow videoWindow )
    {
        long currentStyle = videoWindow.WindowStyle;
        currentStyle = currentStyle & ~lDisableWindowStyles;
        currentStyle = currentStyle | lEnableWindowStyles;
        videoWindow.WindowStyle = (int)currentStyle;

        videoWindow.Width = 1920;
        videoWindow.Height = 1080;
        videoWindow.FullScreenMode = OATRUE;
        videoWindow.Visible = OATRUE;
    }
```

With regards to Tom Morgan as I have read a lot of tricks from his code.